# How to confirm I'm on a VMWare powered VPS?

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-server

I chose a new VPS host partially based on their use of VMware.

I have no reason to doubt that is the case, but would like to know if there is a way I can very the virtuilization platform from inside my CentOS based VPS.

Answer (score 4):

use `dmidecode` to extract info directly from the BIOS.  VMWare has it's own unique bios string.

```
dmidecode --type BIOS
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my ESXi 5 systems which report a Phoenix BIOS

Comment: Try `--type 1` to get system info... or no parameters to get the full list.

Comment: Something like this would work too: dmidecode -s system-manufacturer

Answer (score 2):

You will probably see some "VMWare" branded devices listed in the output of `dmesg` if dmidecode somehow is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Install a tool like `lshw` to check.

Manual page at: http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw
Download RPM at: http://pkgs.repoforge.org/lshw/

Example output:

```
centos5
    description: Computer
    product: VMware Virtual Platform ()
    vendor: VMware, Inc.
    version: None
    serial: VMware-56 4d 55 7b ca 7f 48 a4-be da c1 22 9b 5d f8 bf
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall64 vsyscall32
 [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

If they install VMware tools on the client there will be some way of recognising it, for example, the presence of vmware-uninstall-tools.pl or the VMwareTools rpm.

Failing that, you could also try [installing VMware tools](http://www.vmware.com/download/packages.html) and see what happens...